# Classification of 32 bit integers into 2 classes with uneven probability

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining

I've been given a set of integer data $x_t$ that are all 32-bit unsigned integers. These data have been previously divided into two classes using a function unknown to me as the following:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}a,  & \text{classed as $a$ for $25$ percent of data}\\b,  & \text{classed as $b$ for $75$ percent of data}\end{cases}$$

As you see, the probability of this classification is uneven. It means that more data are classified as $b$ that of $a$.

The data available now includes a set of $1000$ entries of random looking 32-bit integers $x_t$ with their corresponding classification $c_t$.

The question is what clustering or classification algorithm might best suite to guess the class of any given $x \notin x_t$ for sure or at least with probability higher than 90 percent?

Is the fact that $f(x)$ classifies inputs unevenly relevant here? What if $f(x)$ classifies inputs evenly with equal probability of 50 percent? Will that effect the complexity of the problem and then proper algorithms to use?

Comment: You have to discover the rule that classifies them.  One easy way to get the split is to choose two bits of the number and class one of the four combinations of those two bits as $a$ and the other three as $b$.  I would try that first.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What if the rule is highly complex and impossible to guess?

Comment: Then you won't be able to guess how to classify other numbers based on your data.

Comment: So what are clustering and data-mining algorithms for? Are they all based on a knowledge of the rule?

Comment: They are to discover the rule, or an approximation to it.  Maybe the rule is that we consider the first four bits and those that start with $0000,0001,0010,1111$ belong to $a$  and the rest belong to $b$.  If you only look at the first two bits, you will find $75\%$ of the $a$s start with $00$ and $75\%$ of the ones that start with $00$ are $a$s.  You have a classification algorithm that is not perfect, but is far better than chance.

Comment: Are all the possible rules based on bits? Can be there any other type of rules?

Comment: At the worst, somebody may just have taken enough random numbers to choose the $a$ numbers.  Then nothing you do will work.  We are assuming there is a discoverable rule and trying to discover it or some approximation.  My first thought assumes the problem setter is lazy and wants the simplest rule to generate the desired split.  Of course, the setter's idea of what is simple may be different from mine.

Comment: Without more information on the characteristics of the classes you cannot guarantee *anything* about the probability of correct classification.

Comment: @RossMillikan: what is the rationale of taking two bits and classifying with a 25/75 rule ? (Yes I know that these are the given a priori probabilities.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust:  I suggested it because it is the simplest way I can see to get the required mix.  There are no guarantees, but it is a place to start.  He has $1000$ samples, so can see if any pair of bits fits this model.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I tried all combinations of choosing 2 bits out of 32 and none of them seems to be correlated. Any other possibility do you suggest? What algorithms I can use to discover the rules?

Comment: It is a guessing game.  I would move to looking at combinations of more bits and also at the total number of $1$s in the word, things like that.